# Spring Security @Postfilter not being triggered

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

The @Postfilter is not being triggered.

There are two methods in my controller. The listJson method makes a call to list1 method to get all projects and returns them in json format. I have a @Postfilter on list1 method to filter projects and the filter is not being triggered.

The issue is not with configuration. Since for testing purposes, I tried placing the @Postfilter on listJson method and it does trigger. Can you kindly assist me in the matter? I would be very grateful.

```
    @RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String listJson(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    List<Project> items = list1(request, response, Project.class);
    return JsonHelper.toJsonArray(items, request.getContextPath());
    }

    @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')") 
    private List<Project> list1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Class<Project> clazz) {
     Integer[] ia = WebHelper.getDojoGridPaginationInfo(request);
     Integer firstResult = ia[0];
     Integer lastResult = ia[1];

     Entry<String, String> orderBy = WebHelper.getDojoJsonRestStoreOrderBy(request.getP arameterNames());
     Where where = WebHelper.FromJsonToFilterClass(request.getParamet er("filter"));
     List<Project> items = JpaHelper.findEntries(firstResult, lastResult - firstResult + 1, orderBy, where, clazz);
     Integer totalCount = JpaHelper.countEntries(where, clazz).intValue();

     WebHelper.setDojoGridPaginationInfo(firstResult, lastResult, totalCount, response);

     return items;
     }
```

webmvc-config.xml

```
      <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
      <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
      </security:global-method-security> 

       <bean id="myPermissionEvaluator" class="org.springframework.security.acls.AclPermis sionEvaluator">
        <constructor-arg ref="aclService" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.express ion.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" >
        <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="myPermissionEvaluator"/>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the list1 method is on the same class/instance as listJson the security advice will not be called as you are dealing with the method inside the class.

If, however, you were to move the list1 method to a service class that is injected, you will have an advised object that will honor the annotation.

**EDIT** I wanted to make this more clear - so I'm including a diagram that hopefully will explain this more clearly

```
/mapping -> Project.listJson(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) |
                                                                      |
                                                                      |
                                                                      |
                                                            ---------------------
                                                            | listJson          |
                                                            |                   |---------|
                                                            |                   |         |
                                                            |                   |         | list1
                                                            |                   |         |
                                                            |                   |         |
                                                            |                   |         |
                                                            |                   |         |
                                                            |  list1            |<--------|
                                                            |                   |
                                                            |                   |
                                                            ---------------------

/mapping -> Project.listJson(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) |
                                                                      |
                                                                      |
                                                                      |
                                                            ---------------------
                                                            | listJson          |<--------------------------------|
                                                            | svc.list1         |--------->advised(Service)       | run @PostFilter
                                                            |                   |         |                       |
                                                            |                   |         | list1                 |
                                                            ---------------------         |                       |
                                                                                          |                       |
                                                            ---------------------         |                       |
                                                            | Service           |         |                       |
                                                            | list1             |<--------|                       |
                                                            |                   |                                 |
                                                            |                   |---------------------------------|
                                                            ---------------------
```